# Parse Object Change Background Notifications

Tags: parse-server

I'm trying to devise a sync strategy when using Parse on Mac/iOS. Pushing local changes is easy enough, but I'm unsure on how to fetch the most recent `PFObject` changes from Parse.

I'm coming from CloudKit where you can subscribe to record changes. When you save something, your other devices get a background push notification letting them know that a record changed (and what it's `CKRecordID` is) so that you can fetch it and update your data.

I'd like to do something similar on Parse. I've been reading through the docs and I don't see anything for this. I know I can query `PFObjects` and send push notifications, but I don't see a specific application for sending a push on an object change.

Do I have to set up an `afterSave` hook with **Cloud Code**? From what I've read, I can do a class-level hook like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Project", function(request) {
  //...
})
```

But is there a way to do this at the object level? Or can I at least include the changed `objectId` in the push notification payload somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes.
you should use an afterSave (or beforeSave) to trigger a function (in this case, sending push notification) to other clients.

for instance:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Project", function(request) {
  if (request.original){
    // meaning this is an update to the object.
    myPushHandler.push({updatedprojectId:request.object.id});

  } else {
    // the first time this object is created.
  }
})
```

Note: you can also use parse LiveQuery instead of push notification. [Parse Live Query](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#live-queries)